# Biber and biblatex version mismatch despite correct versions installed

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, miktex2.9

So, after a biber update a few days back I get the following message:

> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.5.
>
> This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.11) versions are incompatible.
>
> See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.

In itself this is nothing new and remedied by updating to the newest versions. However, according to Miktex, my currently installed version of biblatex is 3.12.

[image]

Looking into the .bcf gave me:

```
version="3.4" bltxversion="3.11"
```

which confuses me even more. To add to that, a new, clean installation of Miktex 2.9 doesn't have any biblatex version installed (at least according to the package manager) but I still get the same message. To my best knowledge there are no secondary biblatex instances on my system.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you have a multi-user MikTeX installation it could be that you have installed `biblatex` twice: Once as user and once as admin. Run both the user and the admin updater twice to make sure that all packages are up to date. What does `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` return when you run it on the command line? Can you show us the complete `.log` file of a short MWE that loads only `biblatex` and a standard class, please?

Comment: If both the user and admin package manager claim that `biblatex` is not installed you either have remnants of an old installation hanging about that get picked up or you have `biblatex` in your document directory. The easiest way to diagnose that is to have a look at the `.log` file.

Comment: @moewe Running an update in user mode did the trick. I had no idea that these are actually handled as separate instances. Thank you very much for this tip. As I'm new here: Should I put this as an answer, edit my original post or just leave it as is?

Comment: If it's alright with you we can close it as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864, our standard 'how to update my TeX distribution properly?' questions.

Comment: That's fine by me.